# Find the differential$(dy)$

Tags: calculus

Given the function $$f(x) = x^4$$

Find the differential ($dy$) and evaluate it at $x = 4$ and $dx = 0.2$

So:

$$\begin{matrix}
dy = f'(4) \times (0.2) \\
dy = 4(4)^3 \times (0.2) \\
dy = 51.2 \\
\end{matrix}$$

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are indeed correct. You might need to write $dy = 4x^3 dx$ somewhere in the middle since the question also asks "Find the differential $dy$".

Answer (score 0):

$$y=x^4$$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=4x^3$$
$$ dy=4x^3dx$$
at $x=4$ and $dx=0.2$

$$ dy=4(4)^3 (0.2)$$